# Override MARK COMPLETE ribbon button for custom activity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I need to override MARK COMPLETE ribbon button for custom activity i made.

There is a field that needs to be populated for activity to be completed.

I have to check weather field is populated and complete activity if so.

I have a plan to write JS function to check the field and complete activity, and apply this function to the ribbon button using RIBBON WORKBENCH.

I have two questions:
-Is there any JS command that completes activity?
-If i add this function to ribbon button, will it override default 'complete' function, or I need to disable this function somehow?

Feel free to tell if i need to elaborate this questions more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't override the default behavior, you will end up with an out of the box button which will most probably be reverted back to the way it was when a CU is applied or when CRM is upgraded.

Mark as complete triggers an [OnSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720.aspx#BKMK_entityOnSave), leveraging this fact, why don't you on [OnSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720.aspx#BKMK_entityOnSave) look for the save mode value? [Save Mode 58 on activities are Save as Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509060.aspx) and perform your tasks?

```
function onSave(executionContext) {
    var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();
    var saveMode = eventArgs.getSaveMode();
    if (saveMode === 58) { //Mark as complete
        //do something

        //checks failed,don't want the user to mark as complete?
        eventArgs.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: This will probably solve my problem. I will now implement it. I just have to ask where to apply this function?  Should I add it to form, field or ribbon button, or something else. I am new to CRM and some things make a lot of confusion for me.

Comment: CRM --> Customizations --> Form Properties --> Event Handlers --> Form OnSave event - Add an event handler with the above function name and check off "Pass execution context as first parameter"

Answer (score 0):

I made some function based on your response. Hope this will do the job.

```
function onSave(executionContext) {
    var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();
    var saveMode = eventArgs.getSaveMode();
    if (saveMode === 58) {  
        var sendDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ad_sampleproductssenton");
        Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification('sampleId');

        if((sendDate=== null)||(sendDate==="undefined")){
            Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification("You have to populate 'Sample Product Sent On' field!", "ERROR", 'sampleId');
            eventArgs.preventDefault();
            return false;

        }else{
            Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification('sampleId');
        }   

    }
};
```